# How to set different username by repository in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, repository, configuration-files

I am working on projects for different clients using Mercurial as a VCS. I know how to set a default user, but is there a mean to set a *different* user for each project ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just edit the file `.hg/hgrc` inside each repository. It's the same syntax as your `~/.hgrc` but will only affect a specific repo.

In `repo1/.hg/hgrc`:

```
[ui]
username = Foo Bar <foobar@example.com>
```

And in `repo2/.hg/hgrc`:

```
[ui]
username = Something Else <something.else@example.com>
```

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively to setting username for each repository you can use [*Mercurial Dynamic Username*](https://bitbucket.org/Mekk/mercurial-dynamic_username) extension and set usernames for specific locations in your global `~/.hgrc` like this:

```
[extensions]
dynamic_username =

[dynamic_username]
work.location = ~/work
work.username = John Smith <john.smith@serious.com>
hobby.location = ~/hobby ~/blogging
hobby.username = Johny <fastjohny@fantasy.net>
```